# Arduino uno not writing to file

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sd-card

I'd like the arduino to write to a file whenever an ajax call is made. The ajax works, but it doesn't write to the file. All other code inside the ajax handler does execute.

```
void handle_ajax() {
    int startUrlIndex = HTTP_req.indexOf("button");
    int endUrlIndex = HTTP_req.indexOf(" HTTP");
    String url = HTTP_req.substring(startUrlIndex, endUrlIndex);
    int startButtonIndex = url.indexOf("device-") + 7;// 7 is length of device-, I really just want the number.
    int endButtonIndex = url.indexOf("&");
    String button = url.substring(startButtonIndex, endButtonIndex);
    int startStateIndex = url.indexOf("state=") + 6; // 6 is length of state=, I really just want the number.
    String state = url.substring(startStateIndex);
    int device = button.toInt();
    int newState = state.toInt();
    dim_light(device, newState * 12);
    write_config("", "text");
}

bool write_config(String line, String text) {
    configFile = SD.open("config.ini", FILE_WRITE);

    if (configFile) {
        configFile.write("Dipshit");
    }

    configFile.close();
    Serial.println("Works.");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the Arduino StackExchange community. Just a couple of questions to try and clarify the situation: 1. Are you able to write to the SD card outside of your function? I.e., can you write something in `setup()`? 2. Can you expand your code snippet to include the parts where you configure the SD card?

Comment: Where have you defined `SD` and `configFile`? The statement `configFile.close();` belongs into the `{}` just after the line with `configFile.write("Dipshit");`.

Comment: I fixed it already, ran out of RAM again.

Answer (score 0):

You have run out of RAM. Consider moving string literals into flash with thr `F()` macro.

Comment: We've done that before, we don't use any strings right now though.